# How to step through each entry in an SQLite index

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on an SQLite DB Table that has fields "Given name", "Surname", and an index formed from (Surname, Given). The primary index is just an integer Name ID. I want to find the first Surname that starts with a search argument (a character string),

```
SELECT Given, Surname FROM NameTable WHERE Surname>'C' LIMIT 1
```

then either step forward or backward, one row at a time, through the Surname+Given index. I have read the SQLIte "Scrolling Cursor" [article](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor), but that solution doesn't quite fit my program's structure. Saving the most recently retrieved Surname, then querying for Surnames that are less than this one, won't work because it might skip several names that precede the most recent name, but have the same surname.

Since this is based on a simple index, it should be possible to step through the index. Is it possible to reference directly the ROWID of the index (not the table itself)? For example, assuming you have just retrieved the record corresponding to row 1234 of the index, and wish to go backward, how would you accomplish something like this:

```
SELECT Given, Surname FROM NameTable WHERE ROWID<1234 (I realize this ROWID will refer to the table, not the index)
```

The table will contain entries such as:

```
SMITH, ABE
SMITH, BARNEY
SMITH, MARY
SMITH, MIKE
...
```

I don't think I can use the prepare/step approach, because there could be many queries against the DB between scrolls.

As an alternative, how does one make a search argument that concatenates Surname and Given? I could use that as a placeholder.

Thanks in advance, and apologies for being an SQL newbie.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're not wanting the “rowid of an index” because that's a nonsense; indexes don't have rowids in that sort of sense, and you don't do searches over them (instead, they're used to accelerate searches over the tables). You're wanting the rowid of the row, and you can get that at the same time as Given and Surname columns. Once you have the ROWID, you can fetch the next row by looking for the first row whose ROWID is greater than the given (previous) one, and that also matches the other criteria. That will be a reasonably efficient query (or at least not much worse than the original one).

If things are getting really complicated, copy the relevant data into a temporary table and do your paging over that. You'll find that that's faster once the initial query is done.

Comment: [1] According to this SQLite article [link](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#searching), there is such a thing as "advancing to the next row of index".

[2] Incrementing ROWID won't work, as the table rows are in random order. There is no relationship between the ROWID, and the alphabetic order of the names.

[3] The name list could contain 5,000,000 rows. Can we afford to build a temporary table every time? The query will change every time the user enters a new name.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, _time it_ first. “Could contain 5M rows” doesn't matter too much if it _actually_ only contains 500. Also, temporary tables are pretty fast as they don't get written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Joining strings is called "concatenation." The concatenation operator in SQLite is "||". This is an example of concatenating multiple columns into a single column.

```
select
  Given || " " || Surname as "Full Name"
from
  NameTable;
```

If you want to preserve a unique identifier for each row, you can also select the (implicit) "ROWID" column. One could also select the individual name columns, the aggregate column, and the "ROWID" column to have the full dataset.

```
select
  ROWID,
  Given,
  Surname,
  Given || " " || Surname as "Full Name"
from
  NameTable;
```

The question on searching is a bit more involved, as it's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Also, in the case where the user is inputting search criteria, the input could be provided in many different ways, e.g. partial or complete Given name or Surname, partial or complete Given name and surname, orders reversed on given and surname, etc. (complicating search).

So, depending upon how you are allowing input you could search in different ways. The simplest way would be with a "like" operator. Depending on the size of your dataset, you might be able to create a virtual table that concatenates the Given and Surname columns into a single column and use that column for the like comparison. Or, you could use an "OR" operator to allow matches to either the Given or Surname columns.

You may also want to be aware that SQLite supports a full text search engine.
http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: the index was created thus: "CREATE INDEX idxSurnGiv ON NameTable (Surname, Given);" My user enters "Smith, John". I want to find "Smith, John", then I want to back up by one row (alphabetically), and I want to find the previous person, for example "Smith, James". Physically, "James" and "John" could be miles apart in the table, for example James could be at row 12, and John at row 45,676.  I need to step back, one name at a time, and retrieve each name that comes just before "Smith, John". This is basically scrolling backward through a list of names.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish (sorting) is usually done with an "Order By" clause (not with an index). For example: select ROWID, Given, Surname, Given || " " || Surname as "Full Name" from NameTable order by 4 asc;

Comment: So what you & Donal are saying is that I have to build a temporary index, which is a duplicate of an already-existing SQLite index, and manage traversing this temporary index with my own code. Sigh... even xBase/Foxpro (vastly inferior technology) had this feature built-in. OK, thank you both for your time & suggestions.